# How to prove that $\lim_{n\to \infty} g_{n}=0$?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces

**Let $f\in C[0,1]$, $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$; for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, define:

$$
g_{n}(t):=f\left(\frac{t}{n}\right)\sin^{n}t,     \space\space\space\space\space\space  \forall t\in [0,1]
$$
Prove that, in $C[0,1]$, $\lim_{n\to\infty} g_{n}=0$.**

My attempt: Equivalently, let's prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty} ||g_{n}||^{2}=0$; as $f$ is continuous, and $[0,1]$ is compact, $\exists M>0$ such that $f(t)\leq M$, $\forall t\in[0,1]$. Moreover, we can see that $f\left(\frac{t}{n}\right)\leq f(t)$, $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}, \forall t\in[0,1]$. Then, $f\left(\frac{t}{n}\right)\leq M$, $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Fixing $n\in\mathbb{N}$, then:
$$
||g_{n}||^{2}=\int_{0}^{1}g_{n}^{2}(t)dt=\int_{0}^{1}\left|f\left(\frac{t}{n}\right)\right|^{2}sin^{2n}(t) dt\leq M^{2}\int_{0}^{1} \sin^{2n}(t) dt$$
With this in mind, I would  be able to prove that $||g_{n}||^{2}$ is bounded... But, how do I prove that it converges to $0$?  I suppose that is neccesary to prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{1}sin^{2n}(t)dt$ tends to $0$, but I am not able to finish the problem...

Any help/hint would be very useful. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You talk about $C([0, 1])$, but where does the integral come from?

Comment: I'm sorry @Meowdog! I'm considering $C([0,1])$ as the preHilbert space, formed by the set and the dot product defined by $< f,g>=\int_{0}^{1} f(t)g(t)dt$ (when working in $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$); the norm used is the induced norm by this dot product.

Comment: And if you really want to prove the $L^2$ case, then you probably have to use $\sin(t)\leq t$. Or dominated convergence for that matter.

Comment: Alright, but then try one of my hints

Comment: Ok! Taking $sin(t)\leq t$, $\forall t\in [0,1]$, I would have it, directly putting it on my presented attempt, no? (as $\int_{0}^{1} t^{2n} dt =\frac{1}{2n+1}$, which tends to $0$). Thanks for answering!

Comment: Use that if $0\le t\le1$ then $\sin(t)\le\sin(1)=q<1$ and $q^n\to0$ (also use that $f$ is bounded as you have already observed).

Comment: Yes, like you said it @rubikman23